# Automated testing component in java

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have a component written in Java, which accepts some external jar file and identifies the test classes written in it using JUnit and it executes the class using below code:

```
//here cls is class file loaded from the jar
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(cls);.
```

This component works perfectly for all most test classes. The problem exist only when I need to execute the test classes related to Selenium using different browsers. I am confused how to inject the WebDriver (for different browsers) details to test class/jar which is loaded at runtime.

The challenge I am facing here to keep this component as an independent tool.

Comment: you can try to load the specific browser based on an environment variable?

Comment: @Dude,what you are saying is I have to set my browser/webdriver object to an env:variable from my test tool,and implement a mechanism in the testing class to read the env: variable and use it?

Comment: Good hint from Dude: It could look like this: `WebDriver wd = (WebDriver) Class.forName(System.getProperty("driver")).newInstance();`. Set the variable by adding `-Ddriver=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver` to your command line.

Comment: Here ,one doubt, Is there any OS dependency for setting ENV variable.

Comment: @ANP yes that was my intention, also i can think of different jars for different settings, but that seems a little overkill

Comment: One more doubt,How can we set a System variable using a program,here I am not able to run a command